# Получение XML на asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Подскажите лучший способ получение xml отправленного POST запросом на asp.net?
С помощью контрола или парсить post запрос? 
Наиболее красивый и интересный способ.

XML отправляется с помощью webRequest следующим образом:

```
        HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        wr.Method = "POST";
        string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n";
        string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "xml_file", "xml.xml", "text/html");
```

Как получить её на серверной стороне?
Пробовал так:
возвращается пустота.

```
[HttpPost]
public void Confirmation(HttpRequestBase request)
{
    var content = request.InputStream;
    var reader = new StreamReader(content);
    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Response.Write(text);
}
```

без фраймвёрков считался хорошо так:

```
<script language="C#" runat="server">
    public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          var content = Context.Request.InputStream;
          var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(content);
          string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
          Response.Write(text);
    }
```

Comment: Откуда вы собираетесь получать xml? Из базы, из внешнего сервиса (скажем, курсы валют), из WCF-запроса, из веб-формы заполненной пользователем? Мы за вас должны угадать источник? Я не понимаю вопроса. "Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы."

Comment: Какая разница на сколько красиво и изящно у вас это реализовано, пользователь все равно это не увидит, главное чтобы хорошо это все работало.

Comment: На asp.net core _красиво_ делается [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50594973/5045688). Это если все xml однотипные и их нужно именно парсить сразу же.

Comment: Теперь вопрос можно и открыть. Посмотрел вариант @AlexanderPetrov - можно перевести и оставить в качестве ответа, уточнив классический/core.

Comment: Да, я вчера за этот комментарий тоже проголосовал. Ещё нашёл решение где функцией [HttpPost]
        public string Post(HttpRequestMessage request) получают весь xml request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result, но на сервере не удалось это воспроизвести.

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста, отформатируйте содержание вашего вопроса. Не всем понятно, чего вы хотите добиться.

По сабжу: 
Вам поможет [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(myURL, myContent);
var myXmlString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
// десереализую или "парсирую" элементы
// и кладу их куда мне надо
```

Можно прочитать респонс сразу в [XDocument](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/xdocument-class-overview)(после приведения в строку), что бы работать с Linq2Xml.

Comment: Прошу прощения, буду думать как это пререфразировать. Имелось в виду приемщик ХМЛ для того чтобы принимать от разных платформ xml и класть себе в базку.

Comment: @Сергей, `Приемщик` - Какой? Что вы подразумеваете под "приемщиком"? Вы будете ждать Http-запроса из вне? Или вы будете отправлять запросы и получать из ответов XML? Отредактировав ваш вопрос, вы сделали его еще более непонятным.
Опишите цель. Опишите как вы это сделали. Уже после того, как вы это сделаете, будет понятно, нужно ли вам пилить api / http-клиент или еще какую-нибудь муть.